# dual pairing and separation

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization, dual-spaces

Consider the following: $\exists y^* \in R^m \setminus \{0\} $ such that:

$$ y^* ( f(x_0) - k_1) \leq a \leq y^*(f(x) + k_2) \ \forall x \in \mathbb R^n, \ k_1,k_2 \in K \subset \mathbb{R^m} \ f: \mathbb{R^n} \rightarrow \mathbb{R^m}$$

f is convex and K a convex cone.

Why can I write on the right side:   $$y^*(f(x) + k_2) =  y^*(f(x)) + y^*(k_2)$$

Comment: Because $y^*$ is a *linear* functional.

Comment: @uniquesolution: But why is that?

Comment: It is an underlying assumption of the entire calculation. When we "multiply" vectors by other vectors in $R^m$ (and such are $k_1,f(x)$), we are tacitly assuming that the multiplication is the inner product, which is -- of course -- linear.

Comment: But there isn't such an assumption?

Comment: I see. Thank you :)